# long text using quill with formula

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using ngx-quill rich text with angular 14. I have already added the math formula and it works. However, I am facing an issue when I am storing the data after using formula. combined with reactive form, it save a long html text for a small equation.
I just entered this equation \frac{2}{4} + \sum_{4}^{4}4 and in return , in the database I got the text below to stored which seems very long for a small equation.

the quill conntent is rendered in html as : ' <h3 class="fs-4 fw-bold" [innerHTML]="byPassHTML(quillContent )">'

> 

```html
 <div><span class="ql-formula" data-value="\frac{2}{4} + \sum_{4}^{4}4">﻿<span contenteditable="false"><span class="katex"><span class="katex-mathml"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mrow><mfrac><mn>2</mn><mn>4</mn></mfrac><mo>+</mo><msubsup><mo>∑</mo><mn>4</mn><mn>4</mn></msubsup><mn>4</mn></mrow><annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\frac{2}{4} + \sum_{4}^{4}4</annotation></semantics></math></span><span class="katex-html" aria-hidden="true"><span class="base"><span class="strut" style="height: 1.1901em; vertical-align: -0.345em;"></span><span class="mord"><span class="mopen nulldelimiter"></span><span class="mfrac"><span class="vlist-t vlist-t2"><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.8451em;"><span class="" style="top: -2.655em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 3em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="mord mtight"><span class="mord mtight">4</span></span></span></span><span class="" style="top: -3.23em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 3em;"></span><span class="frac-line" style="border-bottom-width: 0.04em;"></span></span><span class="" style="top: -3.394em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 3em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="mord mtight"><span class="mord mtight">2</span></span></span></span></span><span class="vlist-s">​</span></span><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.345em;"><span class=""></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mclose nulldelimiter"></span></span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.2222em;"></span><span class="mbin">+</span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.2222em;"></span></span><span class="base"><span class="strut" style="height: 1.2537em; vertical-align: -0.2997em;"></span><span class="mop"><span class="mop op-symbol small-op" style="position: relative; top: 0em;">∑</span><span class="msupsub"><span class="vlist-t vlist-t2"><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.954em;"><span class="" style="top: -2.4003em; margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 0.05em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 2.7em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="mord mtight"><span class="mord mtight">4</span></span></span></span><span class="" style="top: -3.2029em; margin-right: 0.05em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 2.7em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="mord mtight"><span class="mord mtight">4</span></span></span></span></span><span class="vlist-s">​</span></span><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.2997em;"><span class=""></span></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.1667em;"></span><span class="mord">4</span></span></span></span></span>﻿</span> </div>
```

is that a normal quill behaviour or I need to consider some configuration?

Thank you help

here the link for a video showing how long the text when i am entering that from quill formula: [video showing how long the text from ngx-quill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JENr-HsimA)